# problem in running node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am new to node.js. I followed the download and installation instruction from [Here](http://www.codediesel.com/linux/installing-node-js-on-ubuntu-10-04/).

Problem is now when I try this in my terminal

> node

I get following message

```
No script was specified.
Usage: node [options] script.js [arguments] 
Options:
  -v, --version      print node's version
  --debug[=port]     enable remote debugging via given TCP port
                     without stopping the execution
  --debug-brk[=port] as above, but break in script.js and
                     wait for remote debugger to connect
  --v8-options       print v8 command line options
  --vars             print various compiled-in variables

Enviromental variables:
NODE_PATH            ':'-separated list of directories
                     prefixed to the module search path,
                     require.paths.
NODE_DEBUG           Print additional debugging output.

Documentation can be found at http://nodejs.org/api.html or with 'man node'
```

After that I tried this example :

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(8124, "127.0.0.1");
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8124/');
```

It says : ReferenceError: console is not defined.

I googled this and found that i havent installed nodejs properly so I installed it again but no success :(

Please help !!

Comment: If you type 'node --version' what do you get?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The version in the installation manual is too old.

Do this

```
wget http://nodejs.org/dist/node-v0.4.6.tar.gz
gunzip node-v0.4.6.tar.gz
tar -xf node-v0.4.6.tar
cd node
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

BTW, here are official installation instructions: https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installation